# correlated measurement error in variables

Tags: measurement-error

I am running a two-variable linear regression. Only one variable is measured with error; however, the second variable is interacted with the first, giving rise to correlated measurement errors.

$y = X_1^*\beta_1 + X_1^*X_2\beta_2 + \epsilon$

Suppose the measurement error of $X_1^*$ has mean $0$ and standard deviation $\sigma_{x_1}$. How can I get corrected estimates of the coefficients? (Either proofs or Monte Carlo simulation is fine)

Comment: Rarely should you include x1*x2 but not x2.

Comment: Let's assume (for simplicity) that this is one such rare case.

Comment: The Bayesian approach provides a straightforward solution. Let me know if you are interested.